# Javascript: juego de memorizar imagenes

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear el juego de adivinar imagenes, estas imagenes tendran un cover y se mostraran al hacer click, mi problema es que necesito que cuando encuentre una coincidencia de 2 imagenes similares(misma ruta) yo pueda obtener un aviso de que acerto pero con el siguiente codigo me manda un alert de coincidencia, siendo el mismo path pero diferentes imagenes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var rr;
var h = 0;
var hh = "";
var e;
  $("img").on("click",function(){
      h+=1;
     e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
var path="image/"+e+".jpeg";
   $(this).prop("src",path);

       rr =  path;

      if(h>1){
    if(rr==="image/"+2+".jpeg"){

        alert(rr+"image/"+2+".jpeg");
    }
     if(rr==="image/"+3+".jpeg"){
      alert(rr+"image/"+3+".jpeg");
    }
      if(rr==="image/"+4+".jpeg"){
       alert(rr+"image/"+4+".jpeg");
    }
      if(rr==="image/"+5+".jpeg"){
      alert(rr+"image/"+5+".jpeg");
    }
      if(rr==="image/"+6+".jpeg"){
      alert(rr+"image/"+6+".jpeg");
    }
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: En cada clic generas imagen al azar, eso no es correcto, deberías tener un arreglo con todas las imágenes x2, desordenarlo y colocar en un tablero. Después, detectar si es la primera o segunda imagen que recibió clic para mostrar o comparar con la anterior.